# How can you generate a unique list of random integers?

Tags: python, loops, random, range

My task is to create two functions:
function 1: checks if the randomly generated list is all unique integers
function 2: generates a random list of integers.

my function 1 works. my question is for function 2: I know how to randomly generate integers... But I really can't figure out how to randomly generate a list?

```
import random
#check for unique integers in list
def allunique(x):
    unique_or_not= []
    for item in x:
        if item in unique_or_not:
            return False
        unique_or_not.append(item)
    return True


#need 3 inputs of the # of values to generate, starting # in range of list, ending # in range of list
def list_of_nums():
    num_of_values= int(input("Please enter the number of values you wish to generate:"))
    start= int(input("Please enter the starting # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    end= int(input("Please enter the end # of the values you wish to generate:"))



    for i in range(0,num_of_values):
#have to loop to do it a certain amount of times, append value immediately to list:????
```

Comment: How does this differ in any meaningful way from [your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842576/how-can-you-make-a-list-of-completely-random-integers), where you were provided a link showing this has already been answered?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a set of length `n` of random numbers in range `r` use:

```
import random
def random_int_set(n,r):
  list = set()
  if n > r:
      return set()
  while(len(list) < n):
    list.add(random.randint(0,r))
  return list
test = random_int_set(3,5)
print(test)
```

================================EDIT=======================================
If you need a list of length `n` of random numbers in range `r` use:

```
import random
def random_int_list(n,r):
  list = []
  for i in range(0,n):
    list.append(random.randint(0,r))
  return list
test = random_int_list(3,5)
print(test)
```

Comment: I tried this:     list = []
    for i in range(1,num_of_values):
        list.append(random.randint(start,end))
        return list
    print(list) ,,, but it doesnt work

Comment: Check the first function

Comment: nothing prints..

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to call `randint` once. Just do it multiple times. This could be put into a list comprehension for easy return.

```
def list_of_nums():
    num_of_values= int(input("Please enter the number of values you wish to generate:"))
    start= int(input("Please enter the starting # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    end= int(input("Please enter the end # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    return [random.randint(start, end) for _ in range(num_of_values)]
```

If you want to guarantee unique integers from list_of_nums, you could use a set to test them before return.

```
def list_of_nums():
    num_of_values= int(input("Please enter the number of values you wish to generate:"))
    start= int(input("Please enter the starting # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    end= int(input("Please enter the end # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    retval = set()
    while True:
        num = random.randint(start, end)
        if num not in retval:
            retval.add(num)
            if len(retval) == num_of_values:
                return list(retval)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `set` and `random.randint`:

```
import random

def generate_items(start, end, amount):
  if start < end and not amount < end-start:
    return ("Invalid values entered")

  result = set() # set, to make results unique
  while len(result) < amount:
    result.add(random.randint(start, end))
  return result


print(generate_items(2, 15, 5))
```

Out:

```
{3, 6, 9, 13, 14}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Use the `sample` function in the `random` library.

```
import random
def list_of_nums()
...
    for i in range(0, num_of_values):
        myrandlist = random.sample(range(start, end), num_of_values)
```

The first parameter of the `sample` function is a list of numbers. As we want integers, we can get a list of numbers via the `range function`. The second parameter calls for an `x` number of elements that the list should contain.

--

### Original Answer:

Try generating random numbers and append them to your list.

In your case, a "randomly generated list" is a list composed of integers produced randomly. This goal can be achieved by using the `random` import to add random integers to your list.

Your for loop requires adding numbers to this list. This can be achieved by functions `random.randrange()` or `random.randint()`. For a direct approach with random integers ranging from 1-5:

```
def list_of_nums():
    ... #previous code you've mentioned
    randomintlist = []
    for i in range(0, num_of_values): #where your original for loop begins
        randomint = random.randrange(1, 6) #add +1 to the end value to include 5
        randomint = int(randomint) #convert random type to int type
        randomintlist.append(randomint)
    return randomintlist #to give info on the list you've just made
```

As you've provided a start/stop variable for your function, you can replace numbers 1 and 6 in the example with the corresponding variables:

```
    randomint = random.randrange(start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample(range(start, end), num_of_values)` instead of the for loop:

```
import random

def list_of_nums():
    num_of_values= int(input("Please enter the number of values you wish to generate:"))
    start= int(input("Please enter the starting # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    end= int(input("Please enter the end # of the values you wish to generate:"))
    return random.sample(range(start, end), num_of_values)
```